Ripple effect shows a circle on clicked expanding card
After the Compose Material3 1.3.0 ripple API change the ripple effect looks a bit weird on an expanding clickable card, but it doesn't look like it will be fixed soon:

var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val height by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (expanded) 500.dp else 100.dp)

Card(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(height)
    )
}

Is there a workaround for this other than to disable the ripple completely?

One way to achieve a ripple effect similar to the deprecated API is by using the clickable modifier and setting the ripple radius to fill the parent size.
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val height by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (expanded) 500.dp else 100.dp)

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(
            indication = ripple(radius = 350.dp, color = Color.Blue),
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
        ),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(height)
        )
    }


Note: Blue color has been added for better visibility. Feel free to ignore it.

You can use following extension method to disable rippleEffect completely.
fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(onClick: () -> Unit): Modifier = composed {
    this.clickable(indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}

// To use
Card(modifier = Modifier.noRippleClickable { expanded = !expanded }) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(height)
    )
}

